# Change input from hidden to file

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with changing type of input in javascript.
When I change from hidden to text is ok and is proper displayed but when I change to file input isn't showing.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function show(x,y) {
    if (document.getElementById(y).checked) {
        document.getElementById(x).setAttribute('type', 'file');
    } else {
        document.getElementById(x).setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: What are trying to achieve with that? File inputs are rather tricky to use because it easily leads to security breaches.

Comment: I'm creating small php app which main future is sending mail to allot people so if user select checkboox he will be able to select file with emails separated with semicolon if not he will be only able to type emails by hand.

Comment: @mapek why are you keeping on changing your question ..?

Comment: Sorry, now is ok. I made a mistake on first edit. Now this code should show my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function show(x, y) {
    if (document.getElementById(y).checked) {
        document.getElementById(x).type = 'text';
    } else {
        document.getElementById(x).type = 'file';
    }
}
```

[Fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/at0dvuzt/1/)

```
function show(x, y) {
    if (document.getElementById(y).checked) {
        document.getElementById(x).type = 'text';
    } else {
        document.getElementById(x).type = 'hidden';
    }
}
```

[Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/at0dvuzt/)

[Fiddle3](http://jsfiddle.net/at0dvuzt/2/)

Comment: It isn't my problem this code work also like mine. I have a problem with changing hidden to file.

Comment: on 35.0.1916.153 Debian not, but on iceweasel is ok.

Answer (score 2):

```js
/*JQUERY
function show(x,y){
$(y).change(function() {
    $("#txtAge").text(this.checked);
    if(this.checked) $(x).attr('type','text')
    else $(x).attr('type','file');
});
}
show('#a','#isAgeSelected');*/
//JAVASCRIPT
function show(x,y,z){
var typedefault=document.getElementById(x).type;
document.getElementById(y).onchange=function(){
    document.getElementById('txtAge').innerText=this.checked;
    if(this.checked){
        document.getElementById(x).type = z;
    } else {
       document.getElementById(x).setAttribute('type',typedefault);
    }
};
}
show('a','isAgeSelecteda','text');
show('b','isAgeSelectedb','text');
show('c','isAgeSelectedc','file');

/*
function supportsFileInput() {
  var dummy = document.createElement("input");
  dummy.setAttribute("type", "file");
  return dummy.disabled === false;
}
alert(supportsFileInput());
*/
```

```html
<input id="isAgeSelecteda" type="checkbox">
<input id="isAgeSelectedb" type="checkbox">
<input id="isAgeSelectedc" type="checkbox">
<p id="txtAge"></p>
<input type="hidden" id="a">
<input type="file" id="b">
<input type="hidden" id="c">
```

Comment: Code snippet? When was this implemented? :o

Comment: 35.0.1916.153 Debian but on iceweasel as is is everything ok

Answer (score 1):

Below code should work.

**Javascript code**

```
document.getElementById(selector).setAttribute("type","file");
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$(selector).attr('type', 'file');
```

**Sample code**

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkTest"  onclick="myFunction()">
<input type="hidden" id="hdnFld" />
```

**Java script**

```
function myFunction() { 
    if(document.getElementById("chkTest").checked)   { 
        document.getElementById("hdnFld").setAttribute("type","text");
    } else{
        document.getElementById("hdnFld").setAttribute("type","file");
    }                               
}
```